# Parsing SEC Edgar fundamental data

Tags: edgar

I'm planning on downloading fundamental data (cash flow, income, balance sheet etc) from SEC EDGAR - am planning on downloading ALL the stocks in S&P 500 index . Does anyone know if there is an upper limit on the total amount of data/files that can be downloaded using FTP. Is there a daily limit on data that can be downloaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you were able to get the data/files you needed -- time is running out for FTP. SEC has announced it will permanently terminate FTP service at year's end.

https://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/ftpusers.htm

In the meantime it sounds like they just ask you to be courteous:

> To preserve equitable server access, we ask that bulk FTP transfer requests be performed between 9 PM and 6 AM Eastern time. Please use efficient scripting, downloading only what you need and space out requests to minimize server load.

Answer (score 1):

I use a base url like this to download filings as ftp is shutdown.

```
base_url = "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK="+str(cik)+"&type="+str(type)+"&dateb="+str(priorto)+"&owner=exclude&output=xml&count="+str(count)
```

you just need to fill in everywhere that you see str(*) with relevant information.

I haven't faced any limitation, except when SEC admin blocks me if I send multiple requests simultaneously. To avoid that, I put `sleep(0.5)` between each request.

Comment: If you are using Python, you can take a look at the [SEC-Edgar module](https://github.com/rahulrrixe/sec-edgar). Though this currently only supports Python 2, it is a start and shows how you can go about downloading this data.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the shutdown of the ftp, you may replace the `ftp://ftp.sec.gov/` part of your URI with `https://www.sec.gov/Archives/` and continue downloading in pretty much the same way as before.